# How do i get the result for a NodeList?

Tags: android, xmlnode

Please I want to display the value of a Node in my text view but I am having trouble getting the value of the Node. I have a raw xml file with the name country and with nodes tagged  name,alpha2 and diallingcode.
Below is my code

```
public class NewTester extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

TextView display;
String getinput;
String data,result;
int code;
InputStream instream;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdisplay);

    String dphoneNumber="2345678";

    data=dphoneNumber.substring(0,3);



    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db=dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        instream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mycountries);
        Document doc=db.parse(instream,null);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList=doc.getElementsByTagName("country");

        for(int i=0;i<nodeList.getLength();i++){
            Node node=nodeList.item(i);

            Element ele=(Element)node;
            NodeList Countryname=ele.getElementsByTagName("name");
            NodeList CountryAlpha=ele.getElementsByTagName("alpha2");
            NodeList Countrydial=ele.getElementsByTagName("diallingcode");
            if(Countrydial.item(i).getNodeValue()==data){
                result=CountryAlpha.item(i).getNodeValue();

            }

        }

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    display.setText(""+result);
}
}
```

I get this error

```
 03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity ComponentInfo{com.tester/com.tester.NewTester}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
     03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
   03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
   03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
   03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
   03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
   03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):   at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
   03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
   03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
   03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):   at com.tester.NewTester.onCreate(NewTester.java:61)
   03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
   03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    03-16 16:19:02.478: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  ... 11 more

Comment: You want to list so many country items as like a list in your textview?

Comment: No I just want to get the string for the tagname dialling code.

Comment: Can you print your log error?

Answer (score 3):

replace the code,

```
    Node node=nodeList.item(i);
    Element ele=(Element)node;
```

with

```
    Element ele=(Element)nodeList.item(i);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I replaced the lines of code like you said but the application stile force to close. Any idea where i am getting it wrong

Comment: check replacing i with 0 in the code block,             if(Countrydial.item(i).getNodeValue()==data){
                result=CountryAlpha.item(i).getNodeValue();

}

Comment: because you are running through a loop and it will pointing to the base element rather than ith element.

Comment: Thanks but I still get force to close.
Here is the error(I have attached the error to the edited code above)

Comment: Add this code after taking the input into element,   Node child = ((Node) ele).getFirstChild();
     if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
        CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
        cd.getData(); 
     } // here cd.getData() will return the value you want from xml. You can slo put it separately creating a method